# How to I use the public key Certificates client side

Tags: tomcat, ssl

I have installed the ssl certificates on my server for https.
I need client to use https apace-tomcat.
Which public key certificates of go daddy are to be shared with client.
What are the steps for the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the certificate of the CA registered in your client. If if doesn't work, check the signing chain, you may need the intermediate certificate as well.